# Cancel Punctuator on Kafka Streams after is triggered

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I create a scheduled punctuator on a transformer and I schedule it to run on a periodical basis (using kafka v2.1.0). Every time I accept a specific key I do create a new one like this

```
        scheduled = context.schedule (Duration.ofMillis(scheduleTime),
             PunctuationType.WALL_CLOCK_TIME,new CustomPunctuator(context, customStateStoreName));
```

My issue is that all these punctuators I create run constantly and I cannot find a way to cancel them. I found a snippet in the internet to use

```
    private Cancellable scheduled;

    @Override
    public void init(PorcessorContext processContext) {
        this.context = processorContext;
        scheduled = context.schedule(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(5), PunctuationType.WALL_CLOCK_TIME,
                                     this::punctuateCancel);
    }

    private void punctuateCancel(long timestamp) {
        scheduled.cancel();
    }
```

but this unfortunately seems to cancel only the latest created Punctuator.

I am editing my post just to give some further insight regarding my approach and how this is related with comments made by wardzinia. So my approach is pretty similar just uses a Map because I need to have only one punctuator active per event key so in my Transformer class I initiate

```
   private Map<String,Cancellable> scheduled  = new HashMap<>();
```

And on my transform method I do execute the code below

```
{
 final Cancellable cancelSched = scheduled.get(recordKey);

 // Every time I get a new event I cancel my previous Punctuator
 // and schedule a new one ( context.schedule a few lines later)

 if(cancelSched != null)
    cancelSched.cancel();

 // This is supposed to work like a closure by capturing the currentCancellable which in the next statement
 // is moved to the scheduled map. Scheduled map at any point will have the only active Punctuator for a
 // specific String as it is constantly renewed
 // Note: Previous registered punctuators have already been cancelled as it can be seen by the previous
 // statement (cancelSched.cancel();)

 Cancellable currentCancellable = context.schedule(Duration.ofMillis(scheduleTime), PunctuationType.WALL_CLOCK_TIME,
                new CustomPunctuator(context, recordKey ,()-> scheduled ));

 // Update Active Punctuators for a specific key.

 scheduled.put(recordKey,currentCancellable);   
}
```

And I use that registered callback on my Punctuator punctuate method to cancel the last active Punctuator
after it has started. It seems to work (not sure though) but it feels very "hacky" and not the kind of solution 
that it is certainly desirable.

So how can I cancel a punctuator after is triggered. Is there a way to cope with this issue ?

Comment: Do you schedule new `Punctuator` in `Transformer::transform(final K key, final V value);`?

Comment: Is there any reason, why you couldn't use only one `Punctuator` for all keys? Punctuator could perform work for all keys.

Comment: I think you shouldn't schedule `Punctuator` in `transform` method, because if several `Punctuator` will be scheduled and then application will be restarted, non of those `Punctuator`s will be running.

Comment: I see your point, I could schedule a single punctuator in init and iterate all over the keys stored in some kind of state store I suppose. Thanks I'll give it a thought to see if it can work for me.

Comment: Your approach is correct. It might be a nice feature request to all a schedule to cancel itself. I create a ticket for this: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-7973

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax, Is it proper approach?
If from some reason application will be killed, 
that punctuator won't be restarted on other node, because it was started only based on some (key, value) pair, that could changed after all? It is rather needed to restore already schedule `Punctuator`s

Comment: To restore punctuation, you should scan the store in `init()` and register new punctuations as needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I *think* one thing you could do is the following:

```java
class CustomPunctuator implements Punctuator {
  final Cancellable schedule;

  public void punctuate(final long timestamp) {
    // business logic
    if (/* do cancel */) {
      schedule.cancel()
    }
  }
}

// registering a punctuation
{
  final CustomPunctuator punctuation = new CustomPunctuator();
  final Cancellable currentCancellable = context.schedule(
    Duration.ofMillis(scheduleTime),
    PunctuationType.WALL_CLOCK_TIME,
    punctuation);

  punctuation.schedule = currentCancellable;
}
```

This way, you don't need to maintain the `HashMap` and give each `CustomPunctuator` instance a way to cancel itself.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same situation, just for the people interested in scala I handle it as

```
val punctuation = new myPunctuation()
val scheduled:Cancellable=context.schedule(Duration.ofSeconds(5), PunctuationType.WALL_CLOCK_TIME, punctuation)
punctuation.schedule=scheduled
```

The class

```
class myPunctuation() extends Punctuator{
      var schedule: Cancellable = _
      override def punctuate(timestamp: Long): Unit = {
      println("hello")
      schedule.cancel()
      }

    }
```

Works like a charm